# How to create a new ftp user?

Tags: server, ftp, webmin

I have 10.04 32bit dedicated server. just installed 10min ago.

I need to create ftp and ssh accounts.

I used to use cpanel in my old server. 
Are there any free panel? or how can I create ftp accounts ?

Answer (score 8):

Try [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/).

```
echo "deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
apt-get update
apt-get install webmin
```

Now,  you can access Webmin by browsing to `http://your-server:10000/`.
To login, use root's username and password.

Comment: I still haven't found how to setup FTP users, but am kind of *not believing* what Webmin is showing to me... awesome!

Comment: I use Webmin and always have trouble figuring out how to set up an FTP user. This answer should explain the part after installing Webmin.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an ftp server.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=79588
This has a full process of how to get your ftp user problem sorted.